# Java: how to convert RGB color to CIE Lab

Tags: java, color-space

How can I present object Color in CIE Lab color model.

```
Color c = ...
float[] lab = {0,0,0};
...
c.getColorComponents(ColorSpace.getInstance(???), lab);
```

But I wasn't able to force this work with CIE Lab (despite of the fact that TYPE_Lab is presented in ColorSpace class)

Thx for attention.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's my implementation:

```
import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;

public class CIELab extends ColorSpace {

    public static CIELab getInstance() {
        return Holder.INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public float[] fromCIEXYZ(float[] colorvalue) {
        double l = f(colorvalue[1]);
        double L = 116.0 * l - 16.0;
        double a = 500.0 * (f(colorvalue[0]) - l);
        double b = 200.0 * (l - f(colorvalue[2]));
        return new float[] {(float) L, (float) a, (float) b};
    }

    @Override
    public float[] fromRGB(float[] rgbvalue) {
        float[] xyz = CIEXYZ.fromRGB(rgbvalue);
        return fromCIEXYZ(xyz);
    }

    @Override
    public float getMaxValue(int component) {
        return 128f;
    }

    @Override
    public float getMinValue(int component) {
        return (component == 0)? 0f: -128f;
    }    

    @Override
    public String getName(int idx) {
        return String.valueOf("Lab".charAt(idx));
    }

    @Override
    public float[] toCIEXYZ(float[] colorvalue) {
        double i = (colorvalue[0] + 16.0) * (1.0 / 116.0);
        double X = fInv(i + colorvalue[1] * (1.0 / 500.0));
        double Y = fInv(i);
        double Z = fInv(i - colorvalue[2] * (1.0 / 200.0));
        return new float[] {(float) X, (float) Y, (float) Z};
    }

    @Override
    public float[] toRGB(float[] colorvalue) {
        float[] xyz = toCIEXYZ(colorvalue);
        return CIEXYZ.toRGB(xyz);
    }

    CIELab() {
        super(ColorSpace.TYPE_Lab, 3);
    }

    private static double f(double x) {
        if (x > 216.0 / 24389.0) {
            return Math.cbrt(x);
        } else {
            return (841.0 / 108.0) * x + N;
        }
    }

    private static double fInv(double x) {
        if (x > 6.0 / 29.0) {
            return x*x*x;
        } else {
            return (108.0 / 841.0) * (x - N);
        }
    }

    private Object readResolve() {
        return getInstance();
    }

    private static class Holder {
        static final CIELab INSTANCE = new CIELab();
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5027741380892134289L;

    private static final ColorSpace CIEXYZ =
        ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_CIEXYZ);

    private static final double N = 4.0 / 29.0;

}
```

Comment: @Peter Perháč, the [Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) license applies.

Comment: Excellent - I used this without any problems, however I did make a small change. In my application I converted an RGB image to CIELab color space, performed some processing on the L channel, then converted back to RGB, and noticed ugly artifacts. The solution I used was to clamp the X,Y,Z values calculated in the above `toCIEXYZ` method to the range [0,1]. Not sure if this is the 'right' way to do things, but it got rid of the artifacts.

Comment: @James on behalf of [yasir-gakhar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9446678/yasir-gakhar): Hi James .I have calculated R,G and B values of an image and do some calculations to get L,a and b values for LAB Colorspace. Now how can I transfer my RGB image into LAB image using these L,a and b Values in Android studio (Except OpenCV's Builtin function because I want to first convert RGB into XYZ and then finally XYZ to LAB color space)?

Comment: @jps @yasir-gakhar The implementation in this answer does exactly that - see that the `fromRGB` method calls `fromCIEXYZ`.

Comment: Actually the code in this answer does not render correct results when converting from RGB to Lab. For example, `toRGB(new float[] {30, 30, 30})` gives us RGB values **121 46 31** which is more or less correct (let alone there is no compensation for illuminant, i.e. D50/D65). But `fromRGB(new float[] {121, 46, 31})` gives us Lab values **99.918526 -6.125774 12.3618355**. Not even close.

Answer (score 14):

I had some problems using the code in @finnw's answer.  I believe they were mostly due to the fact that to do a CIELab conversion you should specify an illuminant:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_illuminant

One of the popular standards is [D50](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_illuminant#Illuminant_series_D), which is basically just a standard daylight.  Because @finnw's code doesn't have the correction for illumination, the colors that are supposed to be neutral gray come out slightly tinted.  One way of checking this is to try:

```
 float[] g = { 50.0f, 0f, 0f };
 CIELab.getInstance().toRGB(g); 
 for (float f : g) System.out.println(f);
```

You should get roughly the same number on all three channels, but you end up with an RGB profile that's noticeably (albeit slightly) blue.  I'm sure it is possible to correct this in @finnw's code, but after a bit of playing with it and searching around, I found some excellent conversion code here:

[http://www.f4.fhtw-berlin.de/~barthel/ImageJ/ColorInspector//HTMLHelp/farbraumJava.htm](http://www.f4.fhtw-berlin.de/%7Ebarthel/ImageJ/ColorInspector//HTMLHelp/farbraumJava.htm)

For completeness, here it is.

```
public void rgb2lab(int R, int G, int B, int[] lab) {
    //http://www.brucelindbloom.com
      
    float r, g, b, X, Y, Z, fx, fy, fz, xr, yr, zr;
    float Ls, as, bs;
    float eps = 216.f/24389.f;
    float k = 24389.f/27.f;
       
    float Xr = 0.964221f;  // reference white D50
    float Yr = 1.0f;
    float Zr = 0.825211f;
    
    // RGB to XYZ
    r = R/255.f; //R 0..1
    g = G/255.f; //G 0..1
    b = B/255.f; //B 0..1
    
    // assuming sRGB (D65)
    if (r <= 0.04045)
        r = r/12;
    else
        r = (float) Math.pow((r+0.055)/1.055,2.4);
    
    if (g <= 0.04045)
        g = g/12;
    else
        g = (float) Math.pow((g+0.055)/1.055,2.4);
    
    if (b <= 0.04045)
        b = b/12;
    else
        b = (float) Math.pow((b+0.055)/1.055,2.4);
    
    
    X =  0.436052025f*r     + 0.385081593f*g + 0.143087414f *b;
    Y =  0.222491598f*r     + 0.71688606f *g + 0.060621486f *b;
    Z =  0.013929122f*r     + 0.097097002f*g + 0.71418547f  *b;
    
    // XYZ to Lab
    xr = X/Xr;
    yr = Y/Yr;
    zr = Z/Zr;
            
    if ( xr > eps )
        fx =  (float) Math.pow(xr, 1/3.);
    else
        fx = (float) ((k * xr + 16.) / 116.);
     
    if ( yr > eps )
        fy =  (float) Math.pow(yr, 1/3.);
    else
    fy = (float) ((k * yr + 16.) / 116.);
    
    if ( zr > eps )
        fz =  (float) Math.pow(zr, 1/3.);
    else
        fz = (float) ((k * zr + 16.) / 116);
    
    Ls = ( 116 * fy ) - 16;
    as = 500*(fx-fy);
    bs = 200*(fy-fz);
    
    lab[0] = (int) (2.55*Ls + .5);
    lab[1] = (int) (as + .5); 
    lab[2] = (int) (bs + .5);       
}
```

In my tests, it produces gray values that are appropriately chroma-free, and it is much speedier to boot.

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct implementation? I tried to covert white (255, 255, 255) and the result was (L=255, a=0, b=0) instead of (L=100, a=0, b=0). I also check http://colormine.org/convert/rgb-to-lab for comparison with other color, such as red, yellow, and green.

Comment: It seems `Ls` is scale up to fill [0, 255] range. Returning just `Ls` is sufficient. Also I've omittied `+ .5`s. They seem redundant as they will cause the values to overflow. I can just round the value, which makes more sense.

Comment: Re standard illuminant, D50 "Simulates warm daylight at sunrise or sunset with correlated color temperature of 5003 K. Also known as horizon light."  May be warmer than expected. D65 is "noon" daylight. XYZ ref values: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/whitepoint.html

Answer (score 7):

I used this code and it worked:

```
public double[] rgbToLab(int R, int G, int B) {

    double r, g, b, X, Y, Z, xr, yr, zr;

    // D65/2°
    double Xr = 95.047;  
    double Yr = 100.0;
    double Zr = 108.883;


    // --------- RGB to XYZ ---------//

    r = R/255.0;
    g = G/255.0;
    b = B/255.0;

    if (r > 0.04045)
        r = Math.pow((r+0.055)/1.055,2.4);
    else
        r = r/12.92;

    if (g > 0.04045)
        g = Math.pow((g+0.055)/1.055,2.4);
    else
        g = g/12.92;

    if (b > 0.04045)
        b = Math.pow((b+0.055)/1.055,2.4);
    else
        b = b/12.92 ;

    r*=100;
    g*=100;
    b*=100;

    X =  0.4124*r + 0.3576*g + 0.1805*b;
    Y =  0.2126*r + 0.7152*g + 0.0722*b;
    Z =  0.0193*r + 0.1192*g + 0.9505*b;


    // --------- XYZ to Lab --------- //

    xr = X/Xr;
    yr = Y/Yr;
    zr = Z/Zr;

    if ( xr > 0.008856 )
        xr =  (float) Math.pow(xr, 1/3.);
    else
        xr = (float) ((7.787 * xr) + 16 / 116.0);

    if ( yr > 0.008856 )
        yr =  (float) Math.pow(yr, 1/3.);
    else
        yr = (float) ((7.787 * yr) + 16 / 116.0);

    if ( zr > 0.008856 )
        zr =  (float) Math.pow(zr, 1/3.);
    else
        zr = (float) ((7.787 * zr) + 16 / 116.0);


    double[] lab = new double[3];

    lab[0] = (116*yr)-16;
    lab[1] = 500*(xr-yr); 
    lab[2] = 200*(yr-zr); 

    return lab;

}
```

For the code above I used the formulas provided [here](http://www.easyrgb.com/en/math.php) in order to convert from rgb to XYZ and then from XYZ to CIELab. The results I get are the same with [this](http://colormine.org/convert/rgb-to-lab) online converter.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `TYPE_Lab`, but no corresponding `CS_Lab`. You will need to extend `ColorSpace` and override the abstract methods to convert between XYZ, RGB, and Lab. The required conversions can be found at [Lab color space (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space).

Answer (score 2):

CIELAB seems to be supported only by name in the current Java library - if you look at the source of java.awt.color.Colorspace, you'll see that only a handful of the named color spaces are supported.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to bump an old thread but any new ones would likely get marked as duplicate - I feel the top-rated answers are complex or over-engineered and others are not complete or just lacking in information.

```
public static float[] rgbToLab(int r, int g, int b) {
    return ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_CIEXYZ).fromRGB(new float[]{r / 255f, g / 255f, b / 255f});
}
```

Easy 1 liner using awt.color.ColorSpace - working very well in my practice. You can calculate the distance like so

```
// Euclidean Distance
public static double distance(Color target, Color control) {
    float[] a = rgbToLab(target), b = rgbToLab(control);
    double L = a[0] - b[0], A = a[1] - b[1], B = a[2] - b[2];

    return Math.sqrt((L * L) + (A * A) + (B * B));
}

public static float[] rgbToLab(Color color) {
    return rgbToLab(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue());
}
```

This yields results as so;

```
// Control color = #D9C967
#213B1E | DISTANCE: 2.5532837723818224E-4
#19301C | DISTANCE: 2.74658203125E-4
#1E2D10 | DISTANCE: 2.74658203125E-4
#DDC669 | DISTANCE: 0.0
#DDC56B | DISTANCE: 0.0
#DAC761 | DISTANCE: 0.0
```

Comment: According to [this](http://colormine.org/convert/rgb-to-lab) calculator your solution does not work. My unit tests fails with `Lab(0.43585205078125,0.222381591796875,0.013916015625) was not equal to Lab(53.23,80.1,67.22)` for a pure red i.e., `255,0,0` RGB value. The values are sufficiently different that this is not an issue of comparing doubles.

Answer (score 2):

Old question and still no correct *AND* complete answer. Some of them are incorrect. Some of them are correct but not complete. So I decided to provide mine.

First of all... The default implementation of sRGB color space in OpenJDK 21.0.1 seems to be flawed. I didn't try another versions or JDK, but following is what I get from this one.

Try the following code:

```
        // Default implementation.
        ColorSpace defsrgb = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB);
        float[] start = new float[] {118, 48, 25};

        // To CIEXYZ and immediately back!
        float[] finish = defsrgb.fromCIEXYZ(defsrgb.toCIEXYZ(start));

        System.out.println(start[0] + " " + start[1] + " " + start[2]);
        System.out.println(finish[0] + " " + finish[1] + " " + finish[2]);
```

By all means, you should expect something like this, right? Or at least something very close.

```
118.0 48.0 25.0
118.0 48.0 25.0
```

Unfortunately, you get this:

```
118.0 48.0 25.0
0.9981842 0.9992981 0.9996338
```

I haven't invesigated the issue yet. Just decided to write my own implementation for sRGB color space as well. There are some other reasons to do so. More on this later.

Second thing you should know is that sRGB uses D65 white point.

*(BTW, I'm not going to explain all this color theory and color management mumbo jumbo. It's totally out of scope for this answer. I'm sorry, but I can't write a book on color science here.)*

So. sRGB uses D65 white point. This is very important if you want reproduce the result of, say, Adobe Photoshop. Because Adobe Photoshop uses D50 illuminant for its Lab color space implementation. So you need chromatically adapted algorithm for sRGB conversion to CIEXYZ in this case. And this is another reason why default implementation may be unsuitable, BTW.

I decided to implement conversion with adaptation to D50 Lab color space.

Conversion matrices for D50 are as follows:

```
sRGB -> XYZ:

0.4360747  0.3850649  0.1430804
0.2225045  0.7168786  0.0606169
0.0139322  0.0971045  0.7141733

XYZ -> sRGB:

3.1338561 -1.6168667 -0.4906146
-0.9787684  1.9161415  0.0334540
0.0719453 -0.2289914  1.4052427
```

Illuminant for D50 Lab is:

```
Xn = 96.4212
Yn = 100.0
Zn = 82.5188
```

But if you want to use D65 everywhere, then use the following values:

```
sRGB -> XYZ:

0.4124564  0.3575761  0.1804375
0.2126729  0.7151522  0.0721750
0.0193339  0.1191920  0.9503041

XYZ -> sRGB:

3.2404542 -1.5371385 -0.4985314
-0.9692660  1.8760108  0.0415560
0.0556434 -0.2040259  1.0572252

Illuminant D65:

Xn = 95.0489
Yn = 100.0
Zn = 108.8840
```

Now the most important part — the code.

**sRGB color space**

```
package org.example;

import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;

public class SRGBColorSpace extends ColorSpace {
    private static SRGBColorSpace sRGBColorSpace;

    private SRGBColorSpace() {
        super(ColorSpace.TYPE_RGB, 3);
    }

    public static SRGBColorSpace getInstance() {
        if (sRGBColorSpace == null) {
            sRGBColorSpace = new SRGBColorSpace();
        }

        return sRGBColorSpace;
    }

    @Override
    public float[] toRGB(float[] colorValue) {
        return colorValue;
    }

    @Override
    public float[] fromRGB(float[] rgbValue) {
        return rgbValue;
    }

    private float fTo(float t) {
        if (t <= 0.04045f) {
            return t / 12.92f;
        } else {
            return (float) Math.pow((t + 0.055) / 1.055, 2.4);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public float[] toCIEXYZ(float[] colorValue) {
        // Also normalize RGB values here.
        float r = fTo(colorValue[0] / 255.0f);
        float g = fTo(colorValue[1] / 255.0f);
        float b = fTo(colorValue[2] / 255.0f);

        //  Use D50 chromatically adapted matrix here as Photoshop does.
        float X = (0.4360747f * r) + (0.3850649f * g) + (0.1430804f * b);
        float Y = (0.2225045f * r) + (0.7168786f * g) + (0.0606169f * b);
        float Z = (0.0139322f * r) + (0.0971045f * g) + (0.7141733f * b);

        return new float[] {X, Y, Z};
    }

    private float fFrom(float t) {
        if (t > 0.0031308f) {
            return (1.055f * ((float) Math.pow(t, 1 / 2.4))) - 0.055f;
        } else {
            return t * 12.92f;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public float[] fromCIEXYZ(float[] colorValue) {
        float X = colorValue[0];
        float Y = colorValue[1];
        float Z = colorValue[2];

        //  Use D50 chromatically adapted matrix as Photoshop does.
        float tR = (3.1338561f * X) + (-1.6168667f * Y) + (-0.4906146f * Z);
        float tG = (-0.9787684f * X) + (1.9161415f * Y) + (0.0334540f * Z);
        float tB = (0.0719453f * X) + (-0.2289914f * Y) + (1.4052427f * Z);

        float r = fFrom(tR) * 255.0f;
        float g = fFrom(tG) * 255.0f;
        float b = fFrom(tB) * 255.0f;

        return new float[] {r, g, b};
    }
}
```

**Lab color space**

```
package org.example;

import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;

public class CIELabColorSpace extends ColorSpace {
    private static CIELabColorSpace cieLabColorSpace;
    private final float delta = 24.0f / 116.0f;

    // We use illuminant D50 "CIE 1931 2 Degree Standard Observer" as Photoshop does.
    // Values are normalized.
    private static final float Xn = 0.964212f;
    private static final float Yn = 1.0f;
    private static final float Zn = 0.825188f;

    private CIELabColorSpace() {
        super(ColorSpace.TYPE_Lab, 3);
    }

    public static CIELabColorSpace getInstance() {
        if (cieLabColorSpace == null) {
            cieLabColorSpace = new CIELabColorSpace();
        }

        return cieLabColorSpace;
    }

    @Override
    public float[] toRGB(float[] colorValue) {
        return SRGBColorSpace.getInstance().fromCIEXYZ(toCIEXYZ(colorValue));
    }

    @Override
    public float[] fromRGB(float[] rgbValue) {
        return fromCIEXYZ(SRGBColorSpace.getInstance().toCIEXYZ(rgbValue));
    }

    private float fTo(float t) {
        if (t > delta) {
            return (float) Math.pow(t, 3);
        } else {
            return (t - (16.0f / 116.0f)) / 7.787f;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public float[] toCIEXYZ(float[] colorValue) {
        float tY = (colorValue[0] + 16.0f) / 116.0f;
        float tX = (colorValue[1] / 500.0f) + tY;
        float tZ = tY - (colorValue[2] / 200.0f);

        float X = Xn * fTo(tX);
        float Y = Yn * fTo(tY);
        float Z = Zn * fTo(tZ);

        return new float[] {X, Y, Z};
    }

    private float fFrom(float t) {
        if (t > (float) Math.pow(delta, 3)) {
            return (float) Math.cbrt(t);
        } else {
            return (7.787f * t) + (16.0f / 116.0f);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public float[] fromCIEXYZ(float[] colorValue) {
        float X = colorValue[0] / Xn;
        float Y = colorValue[1] / Yn;
        float Z = colorValue[2] / Zn;

        float L = ((116.0f * fFrom(Y)) - 16.0f);
        float a = (500.0f * (fFrom(X) - fFrom(Y)));
        float b = (200.0f * (fFrom(Y) - fFrom(Z)));

        return new float[] {L, a, b};
    }
}
```

**Testing**

```
package org.example;

import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ColorSpace srgb = SRGBColorSpace.getInstance();
        ColorSpace lab = CIELabColorSpace.getInstance();

        float[] srgbColors = new float[] {118, 48, 25};
        float[] labColors = new float[] {30, 30, 30};

        float[] ciexyz = srgb.toCIEXYZ(srgbColors);
        float[] nsrgbColors = srgb.fromCIEXYZ(ciexyz);

        System.out.println("sRGB: " + Math.round(srgbColors[0]) + " " + Math.round(srgbColors[1]) + " " + Math.round(srgbColors[2]));
        System.out.println("ciexyz: " + ciexyz[0] + " " + ciexyz[1] + " " + ciexyz[2]);
        System.out.println("back to sRGB: " + Math.round(nsrgbColors[0]) + " " + Math.round(nsrgbColors[1]) + " " + Math.round(nsrgbColors[2]) + "\n");

        ciexyz = lab.toCIEXYZ(labColors);
        float[] nlabColors = lab.fromCIEXYZ(ciexyz);

        System.out.println("Lab: " + Math.round(labColors[0]) + " " + Math.round(labColors[1]) + " " + Math.round(labColors[2]));
        System.out.println("ciexyz: " + ciexyz[0] + " " + ciexyz[1] + " " + ciexyz[2]);
        System.out.println("back to Lab: " + Math.round(nlabColors[0]) + " " + Math.round(nlabColors[1]) + " " + Math.round(nlabColors[2]) + "\n");

        ciexyz = lab.toCIEXYZ(labColors);
        nsrgbColors = srgb.fromCIEXYZ(ciexyz);

        System.out.println("Lab: " + Math.round(labColors[0]) + " " + Math.round(labColors[1]) + " " + Math.round(labColors[2]));
        System.out.println("ciexyz: " + ciexyz[0] + " " + ciexyz[1] + " " + ciexyz[2]);
        System.out.println("sRGB from Lab: " + Math.round(nsrgbColors[0]) + " " + Math.round(nsrgbColors[1]) + " " + Math.round(nsrgbColors[2]) + "\n");

        ciexyz = srgb.toCIEXYZ(srgbColors);
        nlabColors = lab.fromCIEXYZ(ciexyz);

        System.out.println("sRGB: " + Math.round(srgbColors[0]) + " " + Math.round(srgbColors[1]) + " " + Math.round(srgbColors[2]));
        System.out.println("ciexyz: " + ciexyz[0] + " " + ciexyz[1] + " " + ciexyz[2]);
        System.out.println("Lab from sRGB: " + Math.round(nlabColors[0]) + " " + Math.round(nlabColors[1]) + " " + Math.round(nlabColors[2]) + "\n");
    }
}
```

It produces the following results (identical to Photoshop's ones):

```
sRGB: 118 48 25
ciexyz: 0.09177336 0.062087793 0.012336753
back to sRGB: 118 48 25

Lab: 30 30 30
ciexyz: 0.0917577 0.062359057 0.01236736
back to Lab: 30 30 30

Lab: 30 30 30
ciexyz: 0.0917577 0.062359057 0.01236736
sRGB from Lab: 118 48 25

sRGB: 118 48 25
ciexyz: 0.09177336 0.062087793 0.012336753
Lab from sRGB: 30 30 30
```

If you want to use this code in your project, feel free to do so. Have fun.