# Calculate RGB use intensity

Tags: java, graphics, rgb

I was making a Gauroud algorithm and when i had calculated point intensity on the edge I didn't know what to do with it. I tried to decide this problem like:

```
    private int getPointRGB(double intensity)
    {
        float[] hsb=null;
        double newCrRed;
        double newCrGr;
        double newCrBlue;
        int nRGB;
//crRed, crGr, crBlue - primary components of edge RGB
        newCrRed = intensity*crRed;
        newCrGr = intensity*crGr;
        newCrBlue = intensity*crBlue;
        hsb = Color.RGBtoHSB((int)newCrRed, (int)newCrGr, (int)newCrBlue, null);
        nRGB = Color.HSBtoRGB(hsb[0], hsb[1], hsb[2]);
     return(nRGB);
    }
```

am I right?

Comment: What do these mean: "RGB in polygon point", "intensity", "primary RGB"?

Comment: Having a hard time understanding this question.  Can you elaborate a bit?  Maybe provide details about the code you have and how it's not working....

Comment: My guess is that it's about a color picker with the RGB color in a 3 axis polygon plus a separate intensity selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If none of the default color choosers are satisfactory, you can create your own custom chooser panel, as discussed in [*How to Use Color Choosers: Creating a Custom Chooser Panel*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html#chooserpanel). For example, you could implement the [CIE 1976 color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space), shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593469/java-how-to-convert-rgb-color-to-cie-lab).