# Convert RGB to CIELAB colorspace

Tags: java, android, cielab

I need to use the CIELAB colorspace in an android app.
The problem is that android doesn't support java awt,which is needed to convert the colors, and I have no idea how to do this without it.

Comment: did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5021831/1778834

Comment: Yes, but this method uses awt and android has no support for awt

Comment: I found a conversion routine on the german wikipedia-article: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab-Farbraum 

The image http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/0/d/0/0d08dc6628d00d4f6d7439183d4f8cc3.png showed the conversion algorithm. Seems very straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

The Android support library now has ColorUtils which can convert to and from CieLAB https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/ColorUtils.html