# Unknown color space exception

Tags: java

I want create Color with Lab color space.

```
Color color = new Color(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.TYPE_Lab), new float[]{0, 0, 0}, 0f);
```

And have exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color space
```

And this exception only for integers `ColorSpace.TYPE_*`, but with `ColorSpace.CS_*` all right.
They write that `ColorSpace.TYPE_*` - "Any of the family of * color spaces.". Please tell me how create true Color with Lab color space for example.

Comment: TYPE_lab just describes a generic LAB color space, you'll have to implement it yourself, AFAIK. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593469/java-how-to-convert-rgb-color-to-cie-lab

Comment: Adrian Leonhard, Thanks! I will try.